# How to add more student records in js object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I add more students record to an angular array like: firstName, last Name, fees (in $scope.student)?

This is what I have:

```
 var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

         mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
               firstName: "Muhammad",
               lastName: "Waqas",
               fees:500,

               subjects:[
                  {name:'Physics',marks:70},
                  {name:'Chemistry',marks:80},
                  {name:'Math',marks:65}
               ],

               fullName: function() {
                  var studentObject;
                  studentObject = $scope.student;
                  return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
               }
            };
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand the question here. But what you aim to do is to create a `students` array in the `$scope`, you can do this.

```
mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
    $scope.students = [];

    $scope.students.push({
       firstName: "Muhammad",
       lastName: "Waqas",
       fees:500,

       subjects:[
          {name:'Physics',marks:70},
          {name:'Chemistry',marks:80},
          {name:'Math',marks:65}
       ],

       fullName: function() {
          var studentObject;
          studentObject = $scope.student;
          return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
       }
    });

    //add more students using .push()
 });
```

There you have your students array in the $scope.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that on `$scope.student` instead create `student` as an object only and create an array `$scope.students` and store each `student` object in that array.SImilarly you can create `var student1,var student2` to store information about other students

```
mainApp.controller('studentController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.students = [];
        $scope.studentFullName = function () {
        };
        var student = {
            firstName: "Muhammad",
            lastName: "Waqas",
            fees: 500,

            subjects: [
                {name: 'Physics', marks: 70},
                {name: 'Chemistry', marks: 80},
                {name: 'Math', marks: 65}
            ],
            fullName: this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
        };
        $scope.students.push(student);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks brk.What About loop through ng-repeat in angularjs if we have two objects in an array?